# Adding a variety of suggested songs to a Spotify radio station or playlist

Tags: audio, music, spotify, pandora

I used `Pandora` until leaving the U.S. for the U.K.  `Pandora` is not available in the U.K., so I am now starting to use `Spotify`.  I only use/used either on a `Windows` desktop computer.

`Pandora` allows you to create your own station.  `Pandora` then suggests songs to add to the station.  You vote thumbs up on suggested songs you like.  You can also add variety to the station by requesting particular artists be added or requesting addition of artists with similar styles.  I cannot figure out how to do that in `Spotify`.

Well, actually I have figured out how to start a station in `Spotify` based on a specific song.  Then similar songs are suggested and I get to vote thumbs up if I like them.  The problem is that the suggested songs are so similar to each other that they are almost clones.

My taste in music is very eclectic and I want a lot of variety in my station.  I have created a list of several hundred songs in `Spotify` under `YOUR MUSIC`, but these songs are not in a playlist or radio station.

Can I create a radio station and add all of the songs under `YOUR MUSIC` to that single radio station, thereby forcing `Spotify` to suggest a greater variety of songs for possible inclusion to the station?

I did try creating a playlist of six songs as a test, but `Spotify` did not suggest additional songs for inclusion to the playlist.  Rather `Spotify` just shuffled the same six songs around over and over.

Thanks for any advice on how to get `Spotify` to suggest a wide variety of songs for inclusion to a single radio station.  I would rather not create multiple stations each devoted to songs of a specific genre.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested, and it is possible to right click a playlist and start radio based on that list.

However, as you say, it does not seem to work as intended. Creating a playlist including both Meshuggah and Vivaldi, resulted in a radio station ignoring the classical theme alltogether, only sticking to death metal.

So all in all, what you're asking is intended to be possible, but based on my tests it isn't.